# Calculating NDFI for every week of the year

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1, sar

I wish to calculate the Normalized Difference Flood Index of every week in a year for a region using Sentinel-1 imagery in GEE. The NDFI equation is,

[image]

I am confused about how to set the reference image. Do I get the driest condition image (the image that has the least amount of dark pixels within the year) of the region and use it for all the images in the year? What if I wish to do it for another year? Can I use that reference image for that year, too?